# How to identify data copy lag b/w Azure EventHub and HDFS blob using Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I'm currently streaming the near real-time data from Azure EventHub to HDFS blob location using spark streaming, this streaming job is running 24/7 and i want to understand is there any data copy lag b/w EventHub and HDFS blob. I know i can do it easily in stream analytics where i have a watermark window that could tell me till how many hours/minutes there is a data lag.  But is there a way i can achieve this in Spark Streaming, is there a piece of code that i could write to see what is the data lag. Please guide me here. Hope my question is clear.

Basically i don't want to lose any data that is available in Azure EventHub but not available in HDFS blob as EventHub holds only 2 days of data, if there is any data lag for more than 2 days then definitely i will lose the data.